# iOS iTunes app icon

Tags: ios, icons, itunes, itunesartwork

I am bit confused on how to use the iTunes app icon when getting ready to distribute. I understand it has to be 512 x 512. But the part I don't get is it has to have no extension? I have extracted a couple apps and their iTunesArtwork is a unix executable. In the iTunes icon sample code from their website, for type, it just says Default data. How do I go about adding my iTunesArtwork to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 512x512 (or better 1024x1024, I think this is a recent requirement as of the new iPad intro) icon file shall be a PNG file.

Don't worry about what you see when extracting the file from a binary. The icon file can be uploaded through the browser and a PNG will just do fine.

Comment: So I should not worry when I go to archive my project and the app icon I see in the Organizer is blurry and obviously not the iTunes artwork file?